# In Ruby is there any advantage to using Integer type over Numeric?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Should I be using Integer or Numeric when using the [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) gem to define model attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Numeric is parent class of Integer.
Integer is most fundamental number class in Ruby. 
Thus the advantage of using Integer over Numeric is simple.

You can use several useful specific methods related with integer(not like float).
I'll be good to refer each document. [Numeric API doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html)! [Integer API doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html)!

And see also Float API doc . This is pretty helpful for make sense of why Integer like class are separated from Numeric.

You'd better make question about why ActiveRecord choose Float and Integer for map Database's data type.